# How to iterate through two arrays simultaneously in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, iteration

I have written the following function in python that when given a start and end orientation, interpolates the orientation using the SLERP method:

```
 def slerp(self, start_O, target_O, t_array):
                ....(other code)
                return (s0[:,np.newaxis] * start_O[np.newaxis,:]) + (s1[:,np.newaxis] * target_O[np.newaxis,:])
```

When the SLERP function is called in the trajectoryMove function, the function returns a list of 500 arrays, which each consists of 4 elements. I am attempting to simultaneously loop through the list of arrays generated by the SLERP function and through the list of x,y and z values that are generated by the function cubicSplineInterpolate. So for example, for the first pose, the x,y and z elements of the position for the first pose are determined by the cubicSplineInterpolate function, and the x,y,z and w elements of the orientation for the first pose are determined by the spline function. The trajectoryMove function should then loop to the second array of the slerp and cubicSplineInterpolate functions simultaneously. How do I do this in python? Do I need to store the result of calling the slerp function in a new array?

```
def trajectoryMove(self):
        newPose = Pose()
        arr1 = []
        arr2 = []
        arr3 = []
        x_axis = [0.001, 0.0039, 0.0160, 0.0334]
        y_axis = [0.009, 0.0239, 0.0121, 0.0034]
        z_axis = [0.009, 0.0199, 0.0821, 0.1034]
        start_orientation = [0.707106781172, 0.707106781191, 2.59734823723e-06, 0]
        end_orientation = [0.151231412, 0.5112315134, 0.0051534141, 0.5]
        self.cubicSplineInterpolate(x_axis,y_axis,z_axis)
        self.slerp(start_orientation, end_orientation, np.arange(0,1,0.001))
        arr1 = self.xLinespace
        arr2 = self.yLinespace
        arr3 = self.zLinespace

        for x, y, z in zip(arr1, arr2, arr3):

            newPose.position.x = x
            newPose.position.y = y
            newPose.position.z = z
            newPose.orientation.x = 0.707106781172
            newPose.orientation.y = 0.707106781191
            newPose.orientation.z = 2.59734823723e-06
            newPose.orientation.w = 0
            self.set_position_cartesian.publish(newPose)
            rospy.loginfo(newPose)
            rospy.sleep(0.05)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try zip() ?

Comment: zip() for which part?